# Gradle can't find the shadow plugin

Tags: java, gradle

A problem occurred while configuring the root project 'preparator'.

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1.
```

Searched in the following locations:

```
         file:/Users/lion-mane/.m2/repository/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/2.0.1/shadow-2.0.1.pom
         file:/Users/lion-mane/.m2/repository/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/2.0.1/shadow-2.0.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/2.0.1/shadow-2.0.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/2.0.1/shadow-2.0.1.jar

Required by:
project :
```

Comment: What's the shadow plugin? Can you find it in https://mvnrepository.com/?

Comment: @pal It's a very common library. https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you only have `mavenCentral()` in your repositories based on the search paths provided.

You need JCenter instead.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
```